# IPtables rule to allow NAT'ed devices to connect to port-forwarded services in the same network

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, nat, port-forwarding

Currently, I'm using the following IPtables setup and unable to figure out how to allow traffic from LAN to port-forwarded services available on my public IP.

The situation:

- ens3: The public facing network interface with one public IPv4 address
- br0: The bridge interface used to connect various LXC containers.

Some services, e.g. a web server, are port forwarded to containers attached to the bridge interface.

The following works:

- Host to container traffic
- container to host traffic
- WAN port forwarded to container traffic from outside of LAN.
- container to container traffic using LAN IPs (e.g. ping 10.10.10.2 from 10.10.10.3)

This does not work (the question):

- Container to container traffic using the WAN IP (e.g. Access HTTP server available on `203.0.113.4:80` which is actually port-forwarded to `10.10.10.2` from `10.10.10.3`

This is my current configuration:

IPTables

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# ens3 is WAN interface, br0 is LAN interface
# We use SNAT instead of MASQUERADING because it is faster, since it doesn't need to look up the source IP to rewrite to on every request and our public IP is static.
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o ens3 -j SNAT --to-source 203.0.113.4

# NAT pinhole: HTTP from WAN to LAN
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i ens3 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:80
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i ens3 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.200:443

COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Service rules

# basic global accept rules - ICMP, loopback, traceroute, established all accepted
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# enable traceroute rejections to get sent out
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33434:33523 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

# DNS - accept from LAN
-A INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# SSH - accept
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# DHCP client requests - accept from LAN
-A INPUT -i br0 -p udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT

# drop all other inbound traffic
-A INPUT -j DROP

# Forwarding rules

# forward packets along established/related connections
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# forward from LAN (br0) to WAN (ens3)
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o ens3 -j ACCEPT

# allow traffic from HTTP NAT pinhole
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.10.10.200 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.10.10.200 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# drop all other forwarded traffic
-A FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

`sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
        address 203.0.113.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 203.0.113.1
        dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address  10.10.10.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

Which IPTables rule or network configuration option am I missing here?

Comment: The thing you are probably looking for is called "Hairpin NAT"